# Chart disappearing immediately after I execute the python code

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

Following is the code to get display a Bar chart using Python (3.6).
Once I execute the following program the chart disappears after 1 sec. Can anyone please help with this.

```
import pandas
import csv
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib


df2 =pandas.read_csv('Place.csv')
place_plot= df2.Place.value_counts().plot(kind="bar",x=df2["Place"],title="Count",legend=False)
fig = place_plot.get_figure() 
fig.show()
```

The `Place.csv` file has the following data,

```
Name    Place
A   India
B   USA
C   India
D   USA
E   China
F   UK
G   Canada
H   China
I   UK
J   UK
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on where and how you execute the code. In a notebook environment it should work fine. However if executed as a script, you should rather use

```
plt.show()
```

instead of `fig.show()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now its working :)

Comment: I want to include one more graph in the program with CSV including one more column Capital ( Capitals of the countries), Im using following code, `capital_plot= output2.Capital.value_counts().plot(kind="bar",x=output2["Capital"],title="Count",legend=False)
plt.show()` . I am getting the output but only after closing the 1st figure. Is it not possible to display 2 figures together?

Comment: Yes, see e.g. [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401102/python-with-matplotlib-drawing-multiple-figures-in-parallel)